# help Finding the Value of limit

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I wanna the values of the limit :

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{|x|}$$

The answer is one of those ($\pm 1,+1,-1,$ undefined).

Comment: Consider one-sided limits: $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$ and $x\rightarrow 0^{-}$. Also, note that $|x|=-x$ if $x<0$ and $|x|=x$ if $x\geq 0$. You should be then able to conclude that the limit is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_n= \frac{1}{n}$ and we see that  $ \lim_{n -> \infty} \frac{x_n}{|x_n|} =1$. Now consider $x_n= -\frac{1}{n}$ $ \lim_{n -> \infty} \frac{x_n}{|x_n|} = -1$.  A sequence can only have 1 limit so the sequence does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

The limit should be calculated from left and right of $0$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{x}{|x|}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{x}{x}=1$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{x}{|x|}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{x}{-x}=-1$$

so the limit is $\pm 1$

Hence the limit not exit

Comment: So, limit does not exist (undefined).

Comment: If there are 2 values for the limit around a point, it is not continuous and is undefined.

Comment: @Jack thanks for your comment

Comment: @Elaiwi, You're welcome.

Comment: sorry guys just to make sure

Comment: +-1 or undefined :D thanks alot

Comment: The one-sided limits are different, so, the limit does not exist (undefined).

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider two limits:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x}{|x|}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x}{x}=1$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{x}{|x|}=\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{x}{-x}=-1$$

Thus the limit is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether you approach the value $0$ from the left or the right. Let's say that $|x| = \frac{1}{n}$ for some positive $n$.

Note that when we approach $0$ from the right $x=\frac{1}{n}$ is positive: $$ \lim_{x \downarrow 0} \frac{x}{|x|} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}1 = 1.$$
On the other hand, if we approach $0$ from the left, $x = -\frac{1}{n}$ is negative, while $|x| = \frac{1}{n}$ is still positive: $$ \lim_{x \uparrow 0} \frac{x}{|x|} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-\frac{1}{n}}{\phantom{-}\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}-1 = -1. $$
So, in this case, the answer depends on whether you approach the limit from the left or the right. Therefore the limit in itself is undefined, as long as it is not specifically stated from which direction you approach the limit.